# How to freeze the first and last column in datagridview in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I need help on freezing the first and last column in datagridview using vb.net.

I have datagridview with 68 columns. I want to freeze the first column in datagridview and I used this code:

```
Datagridview1.Columns("Name").Frozen=True
```

The above code for freezing the first column was correct. But when I try to freeze the last column using the same code (just changed the column name/header text), the scrollbar in datagridview disappear. I want to make the first and last column visible,while still can able to scroll only those columns that were not frozen.

Is it possible to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. Because when you set a column as Frozen, Every column to the left of it is frozen as well. So when you make the last column frozen all other columns become frozen . That's why you are seeing the disappearing scrollbar.

Make your last column the second column so it sits together with the first one. That seems to be the best option

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a more specialised control from DevExpress by example that has this property incorporated.

https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/

It's the best ! ;)

With Visual Studio native controls you are still in the Ice Age...